# Writing multiple inputs into textfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the easiest way to store more than one input in a textfile so that for each time that I run it, a new word is added?

```
randomlist = []
randominput = input()

randomlist.append(randominput)
randomlist.append(randominput)

with open("bleh.data", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(randomlist))
    print(randomlist)
```

This for example only gave me a copy of the first input.

edit: Seems I missed that I wrote "w" instead of "a".Just me not paying attention, It's been solved. Thanks!

Comment: use append mode `a` for `with open("bleh.data", "a") as f:` it will Open for appending at the end of the file without truncating it. Creates a new file if it does not exist.

Comment: What is the data you are getting? strings or numbers?

Comment: I'm trying to make an inventory that can take both strings and numbers and store them until I call for them. Not sure if that clarifies anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for the Python built-in [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).

The `w` flag opens the file for writing and **truncates it first**. You want `a` not `w`.

Alternative you could use [os.lseek()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.lseek). However specifying `w` on your open will always truncate the file to size 0 first, removing whatever you wrote in previously.